# Ionic Capacitor Filesystem

Tags: android, pdf, ionic-framework, capacitor, capacitor-plugin

I am trying to view a PDF file from the assets directory, the file is located under /src/assets/pdf/sample1.pdf under the ionic Application Directory.

When i compile the Application into an android the file reside under /src/main/assets/public/assets/pdf/sample1.pdf

My code looks like below

```
// val = '/assets/pdf/sample1.pdf'
async openpdf(val) {
    fileLocation = this.file.applicationDirectory+'public'+val;
    const file = await Filesystem.readFile({
      path: fileLocation,
    });
}
```

When i try to view the file i am getting the following error message when i trigger this function

> E/Capacitor/Console: File: http://localhost/main.0016603d099c3f92.js -
> Line 1 - Msg: ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: File does not
> exist
> Error: File does not exist

I also tried to check if the directory exist based on the following code and i got the message as the directory exist

```
this.file.checkDir(this.file.applicationDirectory, 'public/assets/pdf/').then(_ =>{
    console.log('Directory exists in the system')}).catch(err =>{
    console.log('Directory not exist')});
```

I also added the appropriate permissions under the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

The same code works fine with iOS without any issue.

Any help solving this issue is grateful, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To check if it is already there in the built code and assets. Have you checked if it is indeed in the following path '{project:home}/android/app/src/main/assets/public/assets' .

This could solve the ambiguity around why it works on IOS so far.

Comment: yes i did check it and it exist under that directory

Answer (score 0):

Solved this with a workaround by copying the file from ApplicationDirectory to the DataDirectory.